# Update with Joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table structures here:

```
employee 
(emp_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(100),
emp_ic VARCHAR(20),
emp_phone VARCHAR(20),
emp_address VARCHAR(200))

employee_medical
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
emp_id INT,
medical_notes TEXT)
```

this is how I select the table:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM employee where emp_id ='$id'";
```

the code that I typed:

```
$sql = "UPDATE employee,employee_medical SET employee.emp_name='a' , employee.emp_ic='b' 
, employee.emp_phone='1', employee.emp_address='1' , employee_medical.medical_notes='1'  WHERE  emp_id=$id";
```

only the medical_notes didn't display.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join the two tables together to be able to update both at the same time. Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE employee 
INNER JOIN employee_medical ON employee.emp_id = employee_medical.emp_id
SET employee.emp_name = 'a', employee.emp_ic = 'b', employee.emp_phone = '1', employee.emp_address = '1', employee_medical.medical_notes = '1' 
WHERE employee.emp_id = '" . $id . "'";
```